# Java and Weka: Creating a string attribute

Tags: java, string, weka, arff

I'm trying to create a Java program that converts a text file to an ARFF file for Weka. Somehow my name attribute is set to numerical, but it should be set to a string. I tried everything, I tried fixing it fixing

```
attr.add(new Attribute("name"));
```

to

```
attr.add(new Attribute("name",true));
```

But when I run it, it prints the names as number (which is in the 2nd column)

```
1,0,?,?,?
1000,1,?,?,?
1002,2,?,?,?
2,3,?,?,?
3000,4,?,?,?
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.DenseInstance;
import weka.core.Instance;
import java.util.*;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffSaver; 

public class WekaCreateARFF {

    private static final String FILENAME = "Some File";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Attribute> attr = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
        Instances dataset;
        double [] values;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        String date = null;
        double id;
        String n = null;

        Instance inst = new DenseInstance(5); 

        List nominal_state = new ArrayList(5);
        nominal_state.add("CA");
        nominal_state.add("NC");
        nominal_state.add("TX");
        nominal_state.add("SC");
        nominal_state.add("NY");

        List nominal_party = new ArrayList(2);
        nominal_party.add("republican");
    nominal_party.add("democrat");

    attr.add(new Attribute("id"));
    attr.add(new Attribute("name",true));
    attr.add(new Attribute("political party", nominal_party));
    attr.add(new Attribute("state", nominal_state));
    attr.add(new Attribute("birth date", date));



    try {

        fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String entry;

        dataset = new Instances("SimpleARFF",attr,0);
        values = new double[dataset.numAttributes()];
        while ((entry = br.readLine()) != null) {

        //System.out.println(entry);
            input.add(entry);
            for (int i = 0; i<5; i++ ) {
                String[] parts = entry.split(",");
                String part1 = parts[0];
                String name = parts[1];                 
                id = Double.parseDouble(part1);



                inst.setValue(attr.get(0), id);
                                    inst.setValue(attr.get(1), name);


            }
            System.out.println(inst);

            dataset.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, values));
        }


        //System.out.println(dataset);
        //ArffSaver arff = new ArffSaver();
        //arff.setInstances(dataset);
        //arff.setFile(new File("Simple.arff"));
        //arff.writeBatch();


    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        try {

            if (br != null)
                br.close();

            if (fr != null)
                fr.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean? is that the source of the error?

Comment: Ok, but that would probably be another question, unrelated to creation of String attributes. If this particular question is solved, mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this constructor:

http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Attribute.html#Attribute-java.lang.String-boolean-

That is, you essentially have to add a boolean flag to tell Weka that you want a `String` attribute, and not a numeric attribute (the default):

```
new Attribute("blah", true)
```

should give you a `String`-attribute.

Comment: when I try that with      attr.add(new Attribute("name",true));     I get a huge error

Comment: How huge can it be... Could you be a little bit more specific? The javadoc states quite clearly that this is a constructor, and that it constructs String attributes.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out-of-bounds for length 0
 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at weka.core.Attribute.value(Attribute.java:778)
 at weka.core.AbstractInstance.stringValue

Comment: This doesn't seem to fit into a comment. I guess it's better if you update your questions, and include the new findings in it. There must be an "edit" button under the question.

Comment: I did it, it is a bit messy